# Shouldn't [music-theory] be renamed to [theory]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Why have the extra word music? It is obviously music or we wouldn't be here :)

Comment: My fault... sorry

Comment: Yes, we need to watch out that we don't introduce music prefixes in our tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agreed.  I went ahead and changed [music-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-theory) to [theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory).  I also added a tag synonym so that someone using [music-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-theory) in the future will automatically end up with [theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory).

Answer (score 1):

I support this change, there shouldn't be any confusion.  <strike>If there are other relevant theories then those ones should have qualifiers, e.g. [piano-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piano-theory).</strike>

Comment: Or you can just tag a post `piano` `theory`…

Comment: That's true.  It doesn't always work -- `bass` `guitar` would be confusing for `bass-guitar`, for example -- but that makes perfect sense.