# Tag for questions about music videos?

Tags: discussion, tags

After reading some of the comments on [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/3889/1061) post, I was wondering:

**Should we have a** [music-video](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-video) **tag?**

(After reading [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/shouldnt-music-theory-be-renamed-to-theory), it seems like the would probably just be [video](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) to stay consistent.)

I would support such a tag (in theory), considering music videos are a significant aspect of musical performance.  But, I'm having trouble thinking of what a good, on-topic question (to which that tag applies) would be - which has me doubting myself now.

Thoughts?

Comment: ..."arguably significant" might be more accurate =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags aren't created independent of questions.  If a set of good on-topic questions are about music videos, the tag will be added.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I'm not sure what was going through my head there.  This makes perfect sense.

Comment: @jadarnel27 No worries. There are some arguments to be made for "guiding" questions with pre-populated tags, but the powers that be are against it from everything I've seen.